# Codeigniter: From constructor to view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to set some data in constructor function, but if I just set it like this: `$data['something'] = 'val';`, it doesn't work. Is it possible to set some data in constructor which would be available in all other functions from the same controller and then in view?

Comment: For a variable to be in the view, you need to pass the `$data` array.  `$this->load->view('page', $data)`.

Comment: Could you please show some more code? This includes the code for the controller and the view

Comment: @user1257255 Try my answer, it works very nice and it is very clear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this on constructor

```
$data['something'] = 'val';
$this->load->vars($data);
```

> Be careful not to use $data['var']=value in other functions if you
>   already declared it in constructor method as it would overwrite the
>   constructor variable

Comment: how can `val` be available to all the functions in the controller?

Comment: Try this man, and you will prove it. If you put this in constructor, than in view you can print it like this <?php echo $something; ?>.

Try it, before downvote please!

Comment: This works for the view, but not the other functions in the controller.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, yes but question was "From constructor to view"

Comment: @ErmanBelegu: From the question: `"... which would be available in all other functions from the same controller and then in view"`

Comment: This answer is solution for my problem. I don't need to set value directly from constructor to view, but from constructor to next function and in this function to view ($this->load->view('view', $data)). Thank you very much! :)

Comment: @user1257255 You asked this: `"... which would be available in all other functions from the same controller and then in view"` and accepting the answer that doesn't do what you said...

Comment: Be careful not to use $data['var']=value in other functions if you already declared it in constructor method as it would overwrite the constructor variable.

Comment: @netrox you are right. I added it in my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

the data that you set 'stuff' will be accessible from all of your controllers if you send it to the view then:

```
<?php

Class Something Extends CI_Controller {

    var $data = array(); //the data variable that will be available in all methods.

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->data['stuff'] = 'do stuff'; //the data that you set on constructor
    }


    function index(){
        $this->data['controller_stuff'] = 'controller stuff';

        $this->load->view('yourview',$this->data); //both the 'stuff' and 'controller_stuff' will be sent to the view like this.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class globalExample extends CI_Controller
{
    public $variable = "wow";
    public function one()
    {
        echo $this->variable; // wow
    }
    public function two()
    {
        echo $this->variable; // wow
    }

}
```